# Hi I want to filter the data in nested array with condition only through filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

let assume I have a list and i want to check the income length is more than 3 digits..

```
const list=[ {name:'Jhon',income:100},{name:'Ellen',income:100},{name:'joe',income:1500}
]

const newList=list.filter((sal) => sal.income.length > 3)
```

Comment: What isn't working? What results are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: please add valid data, the wanted result and what you have tried. btw, dollar is not  known as suffix.

Comment: You should start with valid javascript. Is income a string or a number? `lenght` is misspelled.

Comment: There are typos `lenght`, your data format is not valid

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Okay, so first off, in JavaScript, and most other languages, you can't just have some data like what you've done `1000$`, you best store this kind of data as a string, like I've done in my answer, that will only cause errors in your code.

Then of course, with my answer, you want to get the numeric value of the income, hence the need of `parseInt`, this function will ignore some chars like in this case '`$`', then you can check if the income is greater than `1,000`.

Another note, I'm not sure why you tried that syntax with `{name} => ...`, but there's no need to do it like that, in this scenario, there's no need for the curly braces at all. If anything, if you were to do it like `({name}) => ...`, that would **only** return the name property from the current object, you won't even be able to access the `income` property.

```js
const list = [{
  name: 'Jhon',
  income: '1000$'
}, {
  name: 'Ellen',
  income: '1200$'
}, {
  name: 'joe',
  income: '1500$'
}]

const newList = list.filter(i => parseInt(i.income) > 1000);
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: hi Joe I got this point but  what if i want to return a array whose income digit length is more than 3  digit and income is not string (like income:100)  but  parseInt( i.income.length) >  3 it return empty object.

Comment: and with or without parseInt function.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the property values need to be integers with the dollar sign removed:

```
const list = [ 
    {
        name:'Jhon', 
        income:1000
    }, {
        name:'Ellen',
        income:1200
    }, {
        name:'joe',
        income:1500
    }
];
```

And now you just need to make your function work. Here is how you could do it:

```js
 

const list = [ 
    {
        name:'Jhon', 
        income:1000
    }, {
        name:'Ellen',
        income:1200
    }, {
        name:'joe',
        income:1500
    }
];

var newList = list.filter(e => e.income > 1000);

newList.forEach((e, i) => newList[i] = e.income);

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: Thanks its working but I have some confusion Its returning an object if i want  only income not the whole object.what i have to do.

Comment: @Ashir I have edited my answer

Comment: But I m not getting my exact answer I mentioned in above statement I want to filter the data with only filter function like income length is more than 3 digits